# Как задавать шрифты в aspx-страницах?

Tags: asp.net

Как в asp.net задавать шрифты, доступные по url? К примеру, я хочу воспользоваться шрифтом Open Sans.
В css файле обычно я пишу так.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

А как написать подобное для aspx-страницы. Может быть я что-то делаю не так? И нужно ли писать конструкцию font-face для каждого размера шрифта?

```
<style type="text/css">
        @font-face 
        {
            font-family: 'Open Sans 3';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 300;
            src: url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300');
        }

        .link
        {
              font-family: ? // Как теперь обратится к font-face?
        }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
.link
{
    font-family: 'Open Sans 3';
}
```

И вот эту [статью](http://randsco.com/index.php/2009/07/04/p680) почитайте.